# Botan DTLS Server Error: Can't agree on ciphersuite with client

Tags: c++, winsock2, dtls, botan

I have written a small DTLS Server Example. In the following Link there is my Code:

```
      /****
    DTLSPolicy.hpp
****/

#pragma once

#include<botan/tls_policy.h>
#include<array>
#include<any>

//ENUM Class for Future Versions
//DTLS_ANY is for a possible future feature if you can exclude some Versions. DTLS_ANY will show that no Version is excluded.
//e.g. if there were 1.0 , 1.2 , 1.5 ,2.0 you could set up DTLS_1_0 and exclude DTLS_1_5 as accepted. If DTLS_ANY is set it is not.
enum class DTLSVersion : unsigned int {
    DTLS_ANY = 0,
    DTLS_1_0 = 1,
    DTLS_1_2 = 2
};

constexpr std::array<const char*,19> ACCEPT_ALL_CIPHERS{"AES-256/OCB(12)","AES-128/OCB(12)","ChaCha20Poly1305","AES-256/GCM","AES-128/GCM","AES-256/CCM","AES-128/CCM","AES-256/CCM(8)","AES-128/CCM(8)","Camellia-256/GCM","Camellia-128/GCM","ARIA-256/GCM", "ARIA-128/GCM", "AES-256", "AES-128","Camellia-256", "Camellia-128", "SEED","3DES" };
constexpr std::array<const char*, 4> ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_HASHES{ "SHA-512","SHA-384","SHA-256","SHA-1", };
constexpr std::array<const char*, 4> ACCEPT_ALL_MACS{ "AEAD","SHA-256","SHA-384","SHA-1" };
constexpr std::array<const char*, 8> ACCEPT_ALL_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS{ "SRP_SHA", "ECDHE_PSK", "DHE_PSK", "PSK", "CECPQ1", "ECDH", "DH", "RSA" };
constexpr std::array<const char*, 5> ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_METHODS{ "ECDSA","RSA","DSA","IMPLICIT","ANONYMOUS" };

class DTLSPolicy : public Botan::TLS::Policy
{
public:
    enum class DTLSPolicyOptions : unsigned int {
        //1-9 ALLOWED FEATURES
        DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_CIPHERS = 1,
        DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_SIGNATURE_HASHES = 2,
        DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_MACS = 3,
        DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS = 4,
        DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_SIGNATURE_METHODS = 5,
        //10+ OTHER FEATURES
        DTLS_OPTION_EXCLUDE_DTLS_VERSION = 10,
    };
    DTLSPolicy(DTLSVersion minimum);
    ~DTLSPolicy();
    void setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions option, std::any data);



    //OVERRIDE FUNCTIONS
    bool allow_dtls10() const override {
        return this->dtls10_enabled;
    }
    bool allow_dtls12() const override {
        return this->dtls12_enabled;
    }

    bool allow_tls10() {
        return false;
    }

    bool allow_tls11() {
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allowed_ciphers() const override {
        return this->allowedCiphersVec;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allowed_signature_hashes() const override {
        return this->allowedSignatureHashesVec;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allowed_macs() const override {
        return this->allowedMacsVec;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allowed_key_exchange_methods() const override {
        return this->allowedKeyExchangeMethodsVec;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> allowed_signature_methods() const override {
        return this->allowedSignatureMethodsVec;
    }



private:
    bool dtls10_enabled = false;
    bool dtls12_enabled = false;
    std::vector<std::string> allowedCiphersVec;
    std::vector<std::string> allowedSignatureHashesVec;
    std::vector<std::string> allowedMacsVec;
    std::vector<std::string> allowedKeyExchangeMethodsVec;
    std::vector<std::string> allowedSignatureMethodsVec;
    bool noexclusion = false;

    void excludeVersion(DTLSVersion version);
};

// END

/***
        DTLSPolicy.cpp
***/

#include "DTLSPolicy.hpp"
#include<iostream>


DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicy(DTLSVersion minimum)
{
    switch (minimum) {
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_ANY:
        this->noexclusion = true;
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_1_0:
        this->dtls10_enabled = true;
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_1_2:
        this->dtls12_enabled = true;
        break;
    default:
        std::cerr << "This should not be reached!\n";
        break;
    }
}

DTLSPolicy::~DTLSPolicy()
{
}


//std::any for future options!
void DTLSPolicy::setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions option, std::any data)
{
    switch (option) {
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_CIPHERS:
        {
            this->allowedCiphersVec = std::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(data);
        }
        return;
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_SIGNATURE_HASHES:
        {
            this->allowedSignatureHashesVec = std::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(data);
        }
        return;
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_MACS:
        {
            this->allowedMacsVec = std::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(data);
        }
        return;
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS:
        {
            this->allowedKeyExchangeMethodsVec = std::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(data);
        }
        return;
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_SIGNATURE_METHODS:
        {
            this->allowedSignatureMethodsVec = std::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(data);
        }
        return;
        case DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_EXCLUDE_DTLS_VERSION:
        {
            this->excludeVersion(std::any_cast<DTLSVersion>(data));
        }
        return;
        default:
            std::cerr << "This should not be reached!\n";
            return;
    }
}

void DTLSPolicy::excludeVersion(DTLSVersion version)
{
    if (this->noexclusion) return;
    switch (version) {
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_1_0:
        this->dtls10_enabled = false;
        return;
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_1_2:
        this->dtls12_enabled = false;
        return;
    case DTLSVersion::DTLS_ANY:
    default:
        std::cerr << "OPERATION NOT POSSIBLE\n";
        return;
    }
}

//END

/***
        DTLS.hpp
***/
#pragma once
#define _WINSOCKAPI_ // stop windows.h including winsock.h

#pragma comment(lib,"botan.lib")
#include<iostream>
//BOTAN
#include<botan/tls_server.h>
#include <botan/tls_client.h>
#include <botan/tls_callbacks.h>
#include <botan/tls_session_manager.h>
#include <botan/tls_policy.h>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/certstor.h>
#include <botan/pk_keys.h>
#include<botan/hex.h>
#include<botan/certstor.h>
#include<botan/pkcs8.h>
#include<botan/data_src.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<fstream>

#include"DTLSPolicy.hpp"



class Server_Credentials : public Botan::Credentials_Manager
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Botan::Private_Key> m_key;
//  Botan::DataSource_Stream stream;
    std::ifstream file;
public:
    Server_Credentials()
    {
    }

    std::vector<Botan::Certificate_Store*> trusted_certificate_authorities(
        const std::string& type,
        const std::string& context) override
    {
        // if client authentication is required, this function
        // shall return a list of certificates of CAs we trust
        // for tls client certificates, otherwise return an empty list
        return std::vector<Botan::Certificate_Store*>();
    }

    std::vector<Botan::X509_Certificate> cert_chain(
        const std::vector<std::string>& cert_key_types,
        const std::string& type,
        const std::string& context) override
    {
        // return the certificate chain being sent to the tls client
        // e.g., the certificate file "botan.randombit.net.crt"
        return { Botan::X509_Certificate("botan.randombit.net.crt") };
    }

    Botan::Private_Key* private_key_for(const Botan::X509_Certificate& cert,
        const std::string& type,
        const std::string& context) override
    {
        // return the private key associated with the leaf certificate,
        // in this case the one associated with "botan.randombit.net.crt"
        return &*m_key;
    }


};

class DTLS : public Botan::TLS::Callbacks
{
public:
    DTLS(const std::string& ip, unsigned int port, Botan::TLS::Policy& policy);
    ~DTLS();

    void startReceiving();
    void tls_emit_data(const uint8_t buf[], size_t length) override {
        sendto(this->servSocket, (char*)buf, length, 0, (SOCKADDR*)& this->clientAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
        startReceiving();
    }

    void tls_alert(Botan::TLS::Alert alert) override {
        std::cout << alert.type_string();
    }

    void tls_record_received(uint64_t seq_no, const uint8_t input[], size_t length) override {
        std::string t = "";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            t += static_cast<char>(input[i]);

            if (t[t.length() - 1] == '\t') {
                std::cout << t << '\n';
                t.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    bool tls_session_established(const Botan::TLS::Session& session) override {
        std::cout << "DETAILS:\n"
            << "SESSION ID=" << Botan::hex_encode(session.session_id()) << '\n'
            << "Session Ticket=" << Botan::hex_encode(session.session_ticket()) << '\n';
        return true;
    }



private:
    Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
    Botan::TLS::Session_Manager_In_Memory session_mgr;
    Botan::Credentials_Manager creds;
    Botan::TLS::Policy policy;
    Botan::TLS::Server server;
    SOCKET servSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN servAddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN clientAddr;
};

//END

/***
        DTLS.cpp
***/
#include "DTLS.hpp"
#include<botan/exceptn.h>

#include<ws2tcpip.h>

DTLS::DTLS(const std::string& ip, unsigned int port, Botan::TLS::Policy& policy) : policy(policy),session_mgr(this->rng), server(*this,this->session_mgr,this->creds,this->policy,this->rng,true)
{
    WSAData d;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &d);
    this->servSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    this->servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->servAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    char addr[666];
    if (ip != "ANY")
        this->servAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY;
    else
        this->servAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY;
    auto rc = bind(this->servSocket, (SOCKADDR*)& this->servAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
#ifndef _NO_DEBUG
    if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR)
        std::cout << "COULD NOT BIND!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "SUCCESSFULLY SOCKET BIND\n";
#endif

}


DTLS::~DTLS()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

void DTLS::startReceiving()
{
    try {
        uint8_t buffer[1024];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        int size = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
        auto rc = recvfrom(this->servSocket, (char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (SOCKADDR*)& this->clientAddr, &size);
        buffer[rc] = '\0';
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
        this->server.received_data(buffer, rc);
    }
    catch (Botan::Exception & ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what();
        system("pause");
    }
}
//END

/***
    Quelle.cpp TESTMAIN
***/

#include"DTLS.hpp"

int main() {
    DTLSPolicy policy(DTLSVersion::DTLS_ANY);
    policy.setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_CIPHERS, std::vector<std::string>(ACCEPT_ALL_CIPHERS.begin(), ACCEPT_ALL_CIPHERS.end()));
    policy.setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_MACS, std::vector<std::string>(ACCEPT_ALL_MACS.begin(), ACCEPT_ALL_MACS.end()));
    policy.setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOWED_SIGNATURE_HASHES, std::vector<std::string>(ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_HASHES.begin(), ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_HASHES.end()));
    policy.setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS, std::vector<std::string>(ACCEPT_ALL_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS.begin(), ACCEPT_ALL_KEY_EXCHANGE_METHODS.end()));
    policy.setOption(DTLSPolicy::DTLSPolicyOptions::DTLS_OPTION_SET_ALLOW_SIGNATURE_METHODS, std::vector<std::string>(ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_METHODS.begin(), ACCEPT_ALL_SIGNATURE_METHODS.end()));
    Botan::TLS::Default_Policy p;
    DTLS test("192.168.1.119", 999,p);
    while (true) {
        test.startReceiving();
        Sleep(500);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I tried it with the Qt DTLS Example Client and the botan-cli.exe which can be compiled with the files downloadable on the botan github site.

Even if I code it to work with Linux it will throw the same error. Can someone give me a hint to resolve my Problem?

I have sniffed the Communication via Wireshark too, here is the result:

```
105 CLIENT
107 SERVER

CLIENT HALLO FROM 105 to 107
// START

Frame 161: 567 bytes on wire (4536 bits), 567 bytes captured (4536 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Micro-St_00:95:56 (30:9c:23:00:95:56), Dst: PcsCompu_0c:b9:9b (08:00:27:0c:b9:9b)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.105, Dst: 192.168.1.107
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 58117, Dst Port: 999
Datagram Transport Layer Security
    DTLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: DTLS 1.2 (0xfefd)
        Epoch: 0
        Sequence Number: 0
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 500
            Message Sequence: 0
            Fragment Offset: 0
            Fragment Length: 500
            Version: DTLS 1.2 (0xfefd)
            Random: 75740133b67215d63de54c5c0369444eab560cf4117c34e3...
                GMT Unix Time: Jun 11, 2032 05:19:15.000000000 CEST
                Random Bytes: b67215d63de54c5c0369444eab560cf4117c34e3fb37095e...
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cookie Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 146
            Cipher Suites (73 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a5)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a1)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0069)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0068)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0037)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0036)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0086)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0085)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc02a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc026)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x008d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a4)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a0)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0098)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0097)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0043)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0042)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x008c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
            Extensions Length: 312
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=28)
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=32)
            Extension: heartbeat (len=1)
            Extension: padding (len=223)

//ANSWER from SERVER
Frame 162: 57 bytes on wire (456 bits), 57 bytes captured (456 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (enp0s8)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Apr 28, 2019 00:39:12.189017567 CEST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1556404752.189017567 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001734430 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001734430 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 43.162216943 seconds]
    Frame Number: 162
    Frame Length: 57 bytes (456 bits)
    Capture Length: 57 bytes (456 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:dtls]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: PcsCompu_0c:b9:9b (08:00:27:0c:b9:9b), Dst: Micro-St_00:95:56 (30:9c:23:00:95:56)
    Destination: Micro-St_00:95:56 (30:9c:23:00:95:56)
    Source: PcsCompu_0c:b9:9b (08:00:27:0c:b9:9b)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.107, Dst: 192.168.1.105
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 43
    Identification: 0x9c14 (39956)
    Flags: 0x4000, Don't fragment
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0x1a89 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 192.168.1.107
    Destination: 192.168.1.105
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 999, Dst Port: 58117
    Source Port: 999
    Destination Port: 58117
    Length: 23
    Checksum: 0x844d [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    [Stream index: 35]
Datagram Transport Layer Security
    DTLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: DTLS 1.2 (0xfefd)
        Epoch: 0
        Sequence Number: 0
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

I tried to overload the bool acceptable_ciphersuite in Botan::TLS::Policy in that way it will always return true but it did not help. I googled the error but did not find any suitable solutions for it.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. *Everything* relevant should be contained *in* the question proper.

Comment: I will remember it for the next time

Comment: Why only for "next time"? Why not fix your current question?

Comment: Did it. you can reload and see that the whole code and wireshark results are contained completely. I meant next time I will not use pastebin

Comment: I did it. Have you a clue why it does not want to connect?